# Multiple alarms using PendingIntent

Tags: android, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent

I am creating a scheduler application. In that I am setting multiple events using `AlarmManager` and `PendingIntent`'s. I use following methods:

Here I declare `PendingIntent` array:

```
public static ArrayList <PendingIntent> intentArray= new ArrayList <PendingIntent>();
```

Here I am adding intents to the array:

```
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
        EditScheduleActivity.this, intentid, notifyintent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT); //intent id is unique

alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),
        pendingIntent);
MainActivity.intentArray.add(pendingIntent);
```

Here I am clearing an alarm:

```
EditScheduleActivity.alarmManager.cancel(intentArray.get(selecteditemid_int));
intentArray.remove(selecteditemid_int);
```

But when I clear an alarm, I am getting an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`,I think the problem is when I restart application, intent array list gets re-initialized and throws exception. How can I overcome this problem by keeping the intent array list not to re-initialized?

Comment: But using sharedpreference can we store intent array?

Answer (score 0):

> I think the problem is when i restart application intent array list gets re-initialized and throws exception.

In your case you have to use `Sharepreference or database`, store arraylist into shareprence and while `intentArray.remove(selecteditemid_int);` update your SP, so next time it will give you last stored values, check below links.

[Using preference API in Android applications](http://sudarmuthu.com/blog/using-preference-api-in-android-applications)

[Stackoverflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11050845/646806)

Answer (score -1):

This has very little to do with Android specifically. An `ArrayOutOfBoundsException` means that when you do:

```
intentArray.remove(selecteditemid_int);
```

The `selecteditemid_int` is greater than the length of the array.

Comment: Yes thats what I have told. Intent array gets re-initialized when I restart app.And the array list got cleared.thats why I got array out of bound exception.I need to keep the intent array not to re-initialized.How can I do that?